# How do I diagnose a plugin resource 404?

Tags: admin, security

I'm doing some work for a new client (non-tech, their former tech person left). Their version of Wordpress is 4.3.2.

The site gets some JavaScript errors on load.

Using the Console I noticed two plugin resources don't load throwing 404 (Not Found) errors:

```
/wp-content/plugins/embed_quicktime/jquery-1.2.1.pack.js
/wp-content/plugins/embed_quicktime/jquery.embedquicktime.js
```

However other plugin resources load like:

```
/wp-content/plugins/wp-greet-box/js/functions.js?ver=4.3.2
```

I looked in FTP and all the files and paths are definitely there.

Looking at the filesystem I don't see any permission differences on the folders or files.

I also noticed if I create /wp-content/plugins/wp-greet-box/js/test.html the file loads. it also loads when I create it at /wp-content/plugins/test.html however it 404s when I create it in /wp-content/plugins/embed_quicktime/

I also found when I create a new directory /wp-content/plugins/test/test.html the file is viewable on the website.

I tried renaming /wp-content/plugins/embed_quicktime/ to /wp-content/plugins/embed_quicktime-old/, creating a new folder /wp-content/plugins/embed_quicktime/ and putting test.html in there. However it 404d.

Somehow this WordPress installation is blocking access to the /wp-content/plugins/embed_quicktime/ directory.

I've searched through the database for the string `embed_quicktime` and also through the filesystem. The only database hit was the `wp_options` table (hits on these rows active_plugins, _transient_plugin_slugs, and _site_transient_update_plugins).

I feel like it must be set in the filesystem somewhere...

How do I diagnose this issue?

Comment: Did you check if those files exists?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Yes they exist. I also created a test.html file in each director. in the embed_quicktime test.html 404s and in the wp-greet-box it 200s. I also tested moving test.html up to /wp-content/ and it 200s there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling that either those files don't exist or the location of the file has changed.

Go into `/plugins/wp-greet-box/js/` and see if you can locate the `functions.js` and the `jquery.js`. If the files are not there then they must have been deleted and that is why it's throwing the 404 (Not found).

**EDIT**: Also I would remove some Plugins as a lot of Plugins can cause the page to load slow ect...

Comment: thanks for taking a look. The files are definitely there. WordPress is somehow blocking the /wp-content/plugins/embed_quicktime/ directory. I updated my question with additional information.

Comment: Ar see I just thought they were missing xD Is that the only plugin you have? If not they one of the plugins might be blocking access and so on

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith may I ask what Plugin your using as the embed quicktime plugin I found is outdated by 2 years so just make sure the plugin you have is compatible with the Latest Version of WordPress

Comment: That plugin is Embed QuickTime 1.1 by Andreas Haugstrup Pedersen. This install has 23 active plugins and about 5 related to embedding videos: DOP Player 1.0, EasyVideoPlayer 2.0 1.4.2, Embed QuickTime, Flash Video Player 5.0.4, and FV WordPress Flowplayer 6.0.4.6. I don't think all of them are being used but I don't want to remove any and break something (the site has over 300 pages)

Comment: @codersite, thanks for your help. This site has 23 active plugins and 26 disabled plugins.

Comment: Yeah the Plugin has been outdated for over 2 Years and it was Compatible up to WordPress 2.3.2 not saying it didn't work with version after that but it probably won't work with your version of WordPress, may I ask have you only just updated to the site to WordPress 4.3.2 after the guy left or was it already on that Version before this error appeared?

Comment: lol @CoderSte you were right. The directory /embed_quicktime/ does not exist, the directory /embed-quicktime/ exists though. Thanks again for your help, you were right the first time.

Comment: No problem xD Glad you found the course of it :) Best of luck with your site